# Android In-app Billing network access

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I would like to know if the in-app billing api needs to have internet access when checking if the user have purchased an item or not.

I want to sell game levels using the in-app billing but don't want to access the internet everytime the user starts playing the level.

Does market have any cache mechanism to avoid calling the server everytime? Do I need to implement it on my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of purchases. Managed and unmanaged. Managed products can only be bought once, however unmanaged products can be bought any number of times.

There is no caching as such by the market app. Say for example, you have a managed product ID setup, and you a user has already bought it. The next time you request the market app to buy the same item, it will return with a response, saying "already purchased".

In case of unmanaged items, it just carries out the transaction. 
In both the cases, **internet is required**.

It's upto you how you save the transactions locally, and initiate a purchase by checking if you really need to do another purchase.

Answer (score -1):

You don't even need the Internet permission to use in-app billing. Market will take care of that for you.

Comment: But What I want to know is if the market app needs to access the internet to answer me if the user has bought the item or not.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the in-app billing documentation. You don't ask whether a particular item is purchased, instead Market notifies you when the purchase is complete. It is then up to you to save the result.